# Generate specific ID's in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I seem to be kind of stuck atm. I am trying generating new ID's but it doesnt count the way I would like it to count. 
I have the following xml-file:

```
<componentcontent>
        <explanation>
            <include filename="ha-c41-ep1.xml"/>
            <exercises>
                <include filename="ha-c41-ot1.xml"/>
                <include filename="ha-c41-ot2.xml"/>
            </exercises>
        </explanation>
        <explanation>
            <include filename="ha-c41-u1.xml"/>
            <exercises>
                <include filename="ha-c41-u11.xml"/>
                <include filename="ha-c41-ex-4.xml"/>
            </exercises>
        </explanation>
</componentcontent>
```

I want the explanation files (not the exercise) to have the following id's: filename="1-u1", filename="1-u2" etc.

Currently I use the following xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="componentcontent/explanation/include">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="local:_file" select="local:new-paragraph-filename(., 'u' )"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
            <xsl:number count="explanation/include" level="any"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="c:file[exercise[@type eq 'explanation']]">
        <xsl:variable name="include" as="element(include)?" select="key('includes', @name)"/>
        <xsl:if test="not($include)">
            <xsl:message terminate="yes">Geen include-element gevonden voor file met naam <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>.</xsl:message>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="name" select="local:new-paragraph-filename(key('includes', @name), 'u' )"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @* except @name"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

That gives me the following output:

```
<componentcontent>
        <explanation>
            <include filename="1-u1.xml">1</include>
            <exercises>
                <include filename="ha-c41-ot1.xml"/>
                <include filename="ha-c41-ot2.xml"/>
            </exercises>
        </explanation>
        <explanation>
            <include filename="1-u1.xml">2</include>
            <exercises>
                <include filename="ha-c41-u11.xml"/>
                <include filename="ha-c41-ex-4.xml"/>
            </exercises>
        </explanation>
</componentcontent
```

My question is, can someone point me in the right direction as the count isnt the way I would want it to be?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="explanation/include/@filename">
    <xsl:attribute name="filename">
        <xsl:text>1-u</xsl:text>
        <xsl:number count="explanation/include" level="any"/>
        <xsl:text>.xml</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```